# Properties of RREF 3x3 matrix is the identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

The row reduced echelon form of a 3 × 3 matrix A is the identity. State
whether each of the following is true or false. You do not need to explain your answers.

(a) A has an inverse.

(b) The columns of A are linearly dependent vectors.

(c) The determinant of A is equal to zero.

(d) The equation Ax = b, where x = (x1, x2, x3)T and b = (1, −1, 1)T, has a  unique solution for x1, x2 and x3.

(e) The columns of A form a basis for R^3.

(f) The rank of A is zero

My attempt:

a) True

b) True

c) False

d) True

e) False

f) False

Can anyone check my answers and help me if I'm wrong?

Comment: Every answer follows directly from the [invertible matrix theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#The_invertible_matrix_theorem).  Be sure to recognize the difference between the words *linearly dependent* and *linearly* $\textbf{in}\text{dependent}$.

Comment: (d) is true and $\mathbf{x}=A^{-1}\mathbf{b}$ is the unique solution.

Answer (score 1):

The key is that row operations do not change the row space of a matrix, so if the reduced row echelon form (which is obtained by performing successive row operations) is full rank, then the original matrix must also be full rank. This tells you that it is invertible. The other choices are easy to answer when you realize that this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

How can b and e be both true.

Hint - recall definition of basis

Answer (score 0):

Your answers are correct except for (b) and (e) (for which your answers are incorrect).

If the row-reduced echelon form for $A$ is the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix, then the rank of $A$ is $3$.  So the columns of $A$ are linearly independent and form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.